# Are two 2oz copper layers the same thing as one 4oz copper layer?

Tags: pcb

Let's say I want to use 4oz copper, but the PCB fabrication house does not have that capability.

Can I just use two 2oz copper layers, and route both of them to the same place?

Edit:

I am discharging a capacitor, and I expect very brief current spikes of ~20A

Comment: This needs more clarification of what you need to do

Comment: Do you want 4 oz because you expect high current and need to avoid too high of a temperature rise?

Comment: Use a [trace width calculator](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-pcb-trace-width). You should probably widen existing traces, but could use two or more traces (at risk of introducing loops).

Comment: I need 4oz because I expect very short, high current spikes (~20A). I am discharging a capacitor very fast.

Comment: 2-layer board, or multi-layer?

Comment: Traces are easy (as mentioned below 6mm probably enough for 20A).    I would suggest to be careful you have adequate vias (if you are using vias).   A big fat trace is pointless if you bottleneck the current with a single tiny via somewhere.

Comment: Brief spikes of 20 A isn't the same thing as 20 A continuous. Depending on repetition rate, you can probably get away with much less copper than you think!

Comment: The 20A signal is a capacitor discharging at a rate of 60Hz. Do I just calculate the RMS/average current over a period of time, and then use that as the "continuous" rate of current for my calculations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be surprised to find out what you can get away with on short PCB traces that are only 2 oz copper or less. Clearly though, you have to be aware of track inductance if the current change is very fast because this can produce a large \$L\dfrac{di}{dt}\$ that can cause noise (or worse) in other connected components.

Another general point is that a discharge path should really try and avoid passing currents across a plane; it's better to star-point such connections as much as you can. So, it's a fine line between having a plane that has a very low inductance and small \$L\dfrac{di}{dt}\$ (at the expense of disturbing other connected circuits) AND using a start pointed connection to ground that will have significantly more inductance but far less chance of directly disturbing other circuits.

In my recent experience, I was pulsing up to 165 amps at a frequency of around 100 kHz and I opted for star-pointing. I also wanted 4 oz copper but, due to supply problems could not get it. In the end my tracks were 3 oz copper and about 7 mm wide duplicated on another layer with plenty of connecting vias. I had no problems. Do the math based on this example maybe. 20 amps peak current sounds pretty trivial really.

> *Can I just use two 2oz copper layers, and route both of them to the
> same place?*

That's effectively what I did and it didn't cause a problem. Clearly my current was much higher (165 amps peak, 40 amps valley) but, 7 mm wide tracks on 3 oz copper on two layers worked for me so, maybe scale it down to see what you might get away with.

Comment: Good Grip! ... again. You make me happy to hear that. I am often opposed about the grounding scheme. I see you were not in [this discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/596737/can-i-use-a-split-power-plane-as-an-alternative-to-traces/596744#596744). "165 amps @ 100 kHz" sounds serious business, power grid? motor control? I am proud of you. :-)

Comment: @jay it was for a 10 kW Cuk converter for a customer who shall not be named.

Answer (score 5):

Two questions here

1. is 2x 2oz comparable to 4oz
2. short duration.

**2x 2oz vs 4oz**

No but the difference might be negligible. Why is it "no"?  because of intra-heating

with 4oz copper, a trace width of  6.8mm will  produce approximately 25C temp rise for 20A (steady-state)

with 2oz copper, each taking 10A, a tracewidth of 3.75mm is required for ~ 25C temprise

On the face of it this aligns, half the copper weight but double the number of parallel conductors (to provide the same current capability and current density). However, the two 2oz traces might be in close proximity and thus will heat each other, thus the resultant temperature rise will be higher than +25C.  It might only be +26C and thus its fine

**short duration.**

What about a short pulse of 20A?  well copper can handle an awful large amount of current in a short period. This is covered by **Onderdonk equation**

\$33\frac{I}{A}^2\times S = log_{10}(\frac{\Delta t}{234 + T_a} +1) \$

It is used to determine how long or how much current a piece of metal can carry before it fuses

Answer (score 3):

Using a trace width calculator, for traces on the same layer (inner vs outer), with same length and width, the thickness (2 versus 4 oz) does act as a linear multiplier.

The formula (from the [IPC 2221 standard](https://shop.ipc.org/general-electronics/standards/2221-0-b-english)) for determining track width is:

$$I=k\Delta T^{0.44}A^{0.725}$$

Where \$I\$ = current in amperes, \$A\$ = cross section in square mils, \$\Delta T\$ = temperature rise in °C,  and \$k\$ is a constant (0.048 for outer layers, 0.024 for inner layers).

The esoteric copper thickness system commonly used is based on a given weight of copper being pressed and spread evenly over a square foot area. 1 oz of copper results in a thickness of ~35 µm; 2 oz results in ~70 µm; and so on.

For 20 A on external 2 oz layers, with an allowable temperature rise of 20°C, the recommended track width is about 6 mm. (It's half that, 3 mm, with 4-oz.) But the allowable temperature rise is a major factor. If you allow a temperature rise of 40°C, the width reduces to 4 mm for 2 oz. For short durations or low duty cycles, you are likely okay to accept or use a much higher temperature rise than you would for a track carrying constant current and thus dissipating constant power.

What @Andy has offered is absolutely true as well, so bear that in mind.

Comment: Ipc2221 for current calculations is depreciated

Comment: @JonRB Many calculators still use IPC-2221, but it appears IPC-2152 is a newer one. Is this the one you are referring to?

Comment: yes, far too many online calculators use IPC-2221. IPC-2152 superseding this via a dedicated test campaign. For internal tracks it turned out IPC-2221 was quite pessimistic as there is a reasonable amount of cooling offered even by FR4. But external ... The only reason I call this out everywhere I see this is I have had to deal with a card carrying significant amperage ( 100+) and they swore by a certain calculator "it said it was fine".  At the end of the day they should always be taken as indication only, as a optimistic minimum AND only for below something like 30A. Backed up with FEA

Comment: @JonRB Much appreciated for the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be conservative, you could design the traces to carry 20 A continuously with a 10 C temperature rise in the traces over ambient. From the IPC-2152 standard, this would be 1.2" wide traces and 0.6" wide traces for 2 oz and 4 oz copper respectively.
[image]

[image]

Please note, adding a plane below the trace or using a 20 C rise will reduce the trace width (we use 10 C as our rule in house).

According to the standard, two 0.6" wide 2oz copper parallel traces will carry the same current as one 1.2" wide 2oz copper trace.
[image]